# Using values of loaded registers in rocket-chip custom instructions

Tags: riscv, chisel, rocket-chip

I am trying to add a custom instruction to a freedom e300 rocket-chip.

The custom instruction is to perform an operation using the values of registers a0 to a7 that have been pre-loaded. (Load the values in the a0 to a7 registers with the LUI instruction and then execute the custom instruction)

```
lui a0, val0
lui a1, val1
   :
   :
CUSTOM_INST rd    //<== Calculate using the values of a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7
```

I am trying to modify the ALU module (ALU class in rocket-chip/src/main/scala/rocket/ALU.scala) to add arithmetic operations for custom instructions.

So I want to refer to the values of registers a0 to a7 that have been loaded with values in advance in the arithmetic process, but I don't know how to describe it.

Comment: Look at how regular / pre-existing instructions, like R-Type access the registers.  Not easy, given that's a rocket chip generator, not a rocket chip.  You might generate the code for a rocket chip, and examine that code to see how regular instructions work, then determine how to access a0..a7 in a similar manner, when needed; next work backwards from what you want the chip to do, to how to change the generator to get that.  (Maybe start by hand editing the generator output.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a standardized interface for custom instructions called ROCC. If you have a look at the [Chipyard](https://chipyard.readthedocs.io) documentation, they have a chapter on how you can add custom instructions using this interface: https://chipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Customization/RoCC-Accelerators.html

But more concretely, you will generally have a hard time to add an instruction that works with more than two source registers, since the register file in RocketChip only has two read ports. In general, high numbers of read-ports are hard to impossible to fabricate for a read chip. Instead, consider breaking up your custom instruction into several independent steps. One example could be a custom instruction to load values into your accelerator and a different one to tell your accelerator to compute the result once all values have been loaded.